# Putting embedded image resources into a global array of byte arrays (C#)

Tags: c#, arrays, resources

I'm looking for a way to load a bunch of embedded images into a global array of byte arrays that can be called by reference.  Or if there's a smarter way to do this, that would be great, too.

The purpose is as follows:  I have a handful (will probably be 5-6 in the end) of blank images that will be called, modified, and written out to files (sometimes just .tif files, sometimes embedded into an .xml file).  This is a primary function of the app, and images are called a lot (a typical use of the application might generate 500-1000 images).  Right now I'm using a single embedded image as proof of concept.  I also want the user to be able to choose which images they might use, and then each will be randomly assigned per image created.  In other words, there might be five possible base images, if the user checks two of them, every time an image is called I want it to randomly choose between the two they have selected as options.

The array would allow easy "random" picking each time, and also keep the byte array for each loaded in memory for quicker access (I believe).

So, load all image resources into an array at launch, then copy the needed image form that array each time, modify it and save it out as needed.

Thoughts?

Comment: The resource manager makes them globally available... Why do you need to put them in another array when you can just access them directly?

Comment: Hmm I suppose that's true. I'm looking to speed up the process, partly, and also to be able to call them. I guess I could use an array of their names to perform the random selection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ResourceManager` does cache internally, but there would be no overly compelling reason to use this unless you had assembly-specific (embedded) resources or culture-specific resources. If you did end up using the `ResourceManager`, be sure to use a static, cached reference to it rather than creating a new ResourceManger instance on each request event.

If instead you wanted to load your base images from files on the disk, you could load them into either `Image` or `byte[]` format, whichever was more convenient for the recurring modifications. You could create your own cache class using either an array `T[]`, a `List<T>`, or a `Dictionary<key, T>` as the container (type `T` would be either `Image` or `byte[]` depending on your preference).

Randomly choosing from an allowed subset of the items in the cache is so trivial that this should not be a factor affecting your decision on how to cache/store your resources.